# synchronize react app with google sheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react app, which displays data from a Google Sheet.

It turned out, that I can't fetch data from that Google Sheet directly from the react-client, because it is meant to be running on a server (judge me, if I'm wrong).

Here's my question: can I create a minimal server.js, let's say using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/), which still is static?

The goal is to get it running on a host like github pages, while the data is being refreshed every few minutes.

I have read a few posts and articles (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573218/node-js-react-and-rest-routes-in-same-project), [2](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0)), but I still found no answer to how such a project would be deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know you can't run a server on a hosting platform like github pages, but you could use an button for refreshing. For this maby read this blog post ["Experimenting with React Create App and Google Sheets API"](https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/experimenting-with-react-create-app-and-google-apis)

Also here is the source code on Github: [Link](https://github.com/LeBenLeBen/quotes)

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed it!

In my `index.html` I had to add `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>`, which makes `window.gapi` available everywhere in the app.

My `App.js` now contains a Login functionality, which loads the google client lib.

And finally the data-representing component looks like this:

```
export default class PartnerTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      partners: []
    };

    this.load = this.load.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // Load an initial state
    this.load();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // sync every one minute
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      this.load();
    }, ONE_MINUTE);
  }

  callback(values) {
    this.setState({ partners });
  }

  errorCallback(errorMessage) {
    console.error(errorMessage);
  }

  load() {
    window.gapi.client.load('sheets', 'v4', async () => {
      return window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values
        .get({
          spreadsheetId: '<YOUR SPREADSHEET ID>',
          range: 'A1:E'
        })
        .then(response => {
          const { values } = response.result;
          this.callback(values);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errorCallback(error);
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { partners } = this.state;
    return <div>{'<some way to represent the data, e.g. as table>'}</div>;
  }
}
```